# splitting file1 using AWK and then name the new files based on lines from file2

Tags: bash, awk, sed

File 1 has long string of data between `<PhotoField1>` multiple times.

Example:

```
<PhotoField1>alidkfjaeijwoeij<PhotoField1>akdfjalskdfasd<PhotoField1>
```

File 2 has list of IDs that i want to use to label the Files

Example:

```
A00565415
A00505050
A54531245
```

I have an AWK command to parse each string between `<PhotoField1>` from File1 into its own file, but it only labels the files temp with numbers:

```
awk -v RS="<PhotoField1>" '{ print $0 > "temp" NR }' File1.xml
```

I need to replace the temp* part with the a line from the 2nd file

So the new files would be named A00565415, A00505050, A54531245, etc..
 - it would be excellent  if I could add a .txt to the end of the files: A54531245.txt

The awk command works great for separating it into different files, but i need to be able to name them based on the File2 list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{fname[NR]=$0".txt";next} {print > fname[FNR]}' File2.list RS="<PhotoField1>" File1.xml
```

Comment: This does exactly what i need, the only strange this is that i dont have permissions to the files after they are created.

Comment: That's got something to do with your shell settings. man umask.

Comment: some reason its creating all the files with a ?.txt behind the number. i double checked the list file and their are no spaces so the files looks like this in SSH: A00310433?.txt

Comment: stupid windows, turns out it was a dos formatting issue. i did a dos2unix on file2 and it resolved the issue

Comment: Hey Ed, i am trying to redirect the new files to a different folder but i keep getting syntax errors or it says fatal: dvision by zero attempted. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no division in that script so it cannot be producing a division by zero error. You must have a problem in some other script you're calling it from or elsewhere in your environment. Sorry but I don't have any info to help you debug that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v RS="<PhotoField1>|\n" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0; next} 
      NF{ print $0 > a[FNR] ".txt" }' file2 file1
```

Comment: this kind of works but its restricting the data in the file to one line. the <PhotoField1> String is a huge base64 string. and way more than the onel ine the PhotoField1 is on